# Make row head not start from the first row in 'tabularray' in LaTeX

Tags: tables, tabularray

I know the way to repeat row head from the first row to a certain rows, but how to specify the row head to the second row or the third row?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}\begin{document}
\begin{longtblr}{colspec={*{4}{X[c]}}, rowhead={3}}
nohead&nohead&nohead&nohead\\
nohead&nohead&nohead&nohead\\
head&head&head&head\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
test&test&test&test\\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

Outputs:

[image]

How to repeat the third row but not repeat the first and the second row on the second and next pages?

Comment: Wery unusual demand. For this try to use `xltabular` package. With it you can separate  define column headers for the first page and rest of pages spanned by table and also use `X` columns type.

Comment: @Zarko  Can `tabularray` do this? I use `tabularray` for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

- So far I didn't see any similar demand nor example, so shortly said: this at least is not easy to achieve (or so far not possible).
- Maybe some `tabularray` guru or package author will show, that I'm wrong. Hopefully.
- Meanwhile try to use `xltabular`. With it is simple to achieve desired result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{*{4}{C}}
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}    \\
nohead  &nohead &nohead &nohead \\
nohead  &nohead &nohead &nohead \\
\textbf{head}    
        &\textbf{head} 
                &\textbf{head} 
                        &\textbf{head} \\
\endfirsthead
    \caption[]{My caption (cont.)}                                \\
\textbf{head}
        &\textbf{head}
                &\textbf{head}
                        &\textbf{head} \\
\endhead
\multicolumn{4}{r}{continue on the next page}\\
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
%
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
test    & test  & test  & test  \\
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
One possible way to get what you after by use of the `tabularray` package, is split your table into two parts:

- `tblr` table which contain only first two rows
- `longtblr` table, in which is rest of table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
\begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{capcont}{default}{}    % <---
\noindent\begin{tblr}{colspec={*{4}{X[c]}}}
nohead&nohead&nohead&nohead\\
nohead&nohead&nohead&nohead
\end{tblr}
\vskip-1.5\baselineskip
\begin{longtblr}[
    entry=none,                         % <---
    label=none,                         % <---
                ]{colspec={*{4}{X[c]}}, rowhead={1}}
\textbf{head}
        &\textbf{head}
                &\textbf{head}
                        &\textbf{head} \\
% table body
test    & test  & test  & test         \\
% 
% rest of the table body
% 
\end{longtblr}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Result is the same as before:

[image]